# How and where can I deposit money to generate future payments / income?

Tags: deposits, interest, income

My Question.
What do I deposit now, today, to pay myself $300.00 per week,i.e. $15,600.00 annually at 5% interest for 10 years? What kind of or type of financial institution do I deposit the
in? A few names for example please.

Thank you for your time and great service.

Answer (score 8):

Reversing your math, I am assuming you have $312K to work with.  In that case, I would simply shop around your local banks and/or credit unions and have them compete for your money and you might be quite surprised how much they are willing to pay.

A couple of months ago, you would be able to get about 4.25% from Israel Bonds in Canada on 5 years term (the Jubilee product, with minimum investment of $25K).  It's a bit lower now, but you should still be able to get very good rates if you shop around tier-2 banks or credit unions (who are more hungry for capital than the well-funded tier-1 banks).

Or you could look at preferred shares of a large corporation.  They are different from common shares in the sense they are priced according to the payout rate (i.e. people buy it for the dividend). A quick screen from your favorite stock exchange ought to find you a few options.

Another option is commercial bonds.  You should be able to get that kind of return from investment grade (BBB- and higher) bonds on large corporations these days.  I just did a quick glance at MarketWatch's Bond section (http://cxa.marketwatch.com/finra/BondCenter/Default.aspx) and found AAA grade bonds that will yield > 5%.  You will need to investigate their underlying fundamentals, coupon rate and etc before investing (second thought, grab a introduction to bonds book from Chapters first).

Hope these helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the USA and looking to retire in 10 years, pay your Social Security taxes? :P

Just kidding. Do a search for [Fixed Rate Annuities](http://www.google.com/search?q=fixed+rate+annuities).